# Showing estimate in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

I've been puzzling with a math problem for a while and hope you can help me.

> There is given a Hilbert space $H$ with an orthonormal basis
> $(v_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ and an increasing sequence $(\lambda_i)_{i
> > \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{R}_0^+$, so $0<\lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2 \leq ... \rightarrow \infty$.
> Furthermore, we define the set
> $S:= \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \alpha_i v_i, \textit{where }\alpha_i
> > \in \mathbb{R} \textit{ and } \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \alpha_i^2 \lambda_i\leq 1 \right\}$.
>
> Show that
> $\inf_{E_n \subseteq H, dim(E_n)= n} \sup_{u \in S} \inf_{v \in E_n} ||u-v||_H = (\lambda_{n+1})^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.

I think I understood the statement itself and tried to show two inequalities, $\leq$ and $\geq$ to prove this fact. Unfortunately, neither of them was finished successfully.

I started with $||u-v||_H^2 = (u-v,u-v)_H$ and used the representation of $u\in S$ and $v \in E_n$ by the orthonormal basis. $u = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \alpha_i v_i$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \alpha_i^2 \lambda_i \leq 1$ and $v = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \beta_k v_k$. Here I assumed, that basis vectors of $E_n$ are the first $n$ in $S$. But this assumption is just for convenience and can be removed if necesesary by a more complicated notation.

After simplifying the expression above by using the properties of the scalar product I got stuck since I didn't see a connection between the coefficients $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and although I can insert $\lambda_i$'s in the $(u,u)_X$-term I couldn't argue to get an expression with only $\lambda_{n+1}$ as required.

So maybe I am completely wrong or there is some (easy?) argument, that I don't see.

Does anyone have hints/ can help me with this problem?

Comment: Where did you meet this problem? It seems very weird to me.

Comment: It appeared as a problem in connection with the spectral theorem (I would say the lambdas kind of indicate that they might be eigenvalues, the ascending series might indicate that it could have something to do with the Poisson problem as eigenvalue problem) but since there is no operator given, I'm not sure, so it seems quite weird to me too.